# Code for creating histogram gives me an error

Tags: python

Could you please check the code. Why does it give me an error.

```
figure()
vals = []
dieVals = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
for i in range(10000):
    vals.append(random.choice(dievals)+random.choice(dievals))
hist(vals, bins=11)
show()
```

and following is the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   python files\lec18.py", line 25, in <module>
    vals.append(random.choice(dievals)+random.choice(dievals))
NameError: name 'dievals' is not defined
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a simple typo.

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo between

```
dieVals
```

and

```
dievals
   ^
   ^
```

the error message is giving you a big clue about this. Change `dievals` to `dieVals` in both places it appears in the code inside your loop.

Answer (score 0):

Variable names are case sensitive. You have `dieVals` and further you try to access `dievals`.